Visual Studio Code "Format On Save" breaks code block formatting (Javascript inside ERB)
Codeblock inside Javascript breaks
I have following native code escape blocks inside ERB file
let hide_registration = <%= @user.skip_registration? %>

After I hit save, it gets formatted like this:
let hide_registration = < %= @user.skip_registration ? % >

Which totally breaks the code.
I had to take "Format On Save" feature off.
I have following ERB code extension:
Simple Ruby ERB  v0.2.1
How to solve that so I can start using "Format On Save" again with confidence?
Is there easy way to tell which formatter does that change so I can get rid of it?

If you trigger the command Format document with, is there multiple available formatter? What about if you select one which is not the default?

When I start typing command "Format document with" menu will prompt:
Format document,
Format document (forced),
Format erb files,
Format modified lines.
After enter it will say Extension 'prettier - Code Formatter' is configured formatter but it cannot format 'html.erb' -files
